# Hebrew font PUA mark not placed correctly in Word

Tags: fonts, ms-word, typography, fontforge

I am modifying a Unicode Hebrew font using FontForge.  I added a glyph at U+05C9 in the Hebrew PUA range and named it "dageshhazaq".  I copied to that glyph the glyph for U+5BC "dagesh" (including all Anchors) and proceeded to add "dageshhazaq" to all lookup tables that contained "dagesh".  In the Metrics window, the "dageshhazaq" mark appears correctly, within the base glyph.  However, after generating the font and going to Word, I can insert the "dageshhazaq", but it is not placed correctly.

1. Am I correct that the problem is not with the font, but with Word?
2. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should avoid assigning your own new characters to reserved Unicode slots. Rather than use U+05C9 you should assign it to a slot in the Private Use range U+E000 to U+F8FF. That's probably not why Word has failed to display it correctly, but it could cause problems, especially for future compatibility when Unicode encodes something else there!

From my investigations, it seems that Word 2010+ does support mark positioning and mark-to-mark positioning. I've seen this working, including in a font of my own construction.

Your mark glyph will need to have the right OT Glyph Class set: "Mark" (in the Glyph Info dialog). Marks should have zero advance width.
You need to create a Mark anchor of the appropriate class, appropriately positioned. You should be able to see and adjust the positioning of your mark against base-glyphs via **Element > Font Info > Lookups > GPOS > [your mark table] > [your mark subtable] > Edit Data > [your mark class] > Anchor Control**. This should open a dialog in which you can fine-tune the positioning of mark anchors, and if you get this far it's a promising sign.

Remember to generate your font as OpenType! There is a compounding problem in Windows that I haven't yet figured out how to resolve, which is that Windows sometimes caches an old version of your font somewhere and silently fails to update it, even if you explicitly delete the prior version from the Fonts folder first. This can make it appear that your fix has failed to change anything.

Even if you can get it working in Word, it's still best practice to position the mark to look as good as possible in software that doesn't handle OpenType mark positioning. Copy a meyim or similar onto the background layer and position your dageshhazaq relative to that: counter-intuitively it will be to the right of the glyph origin, even though we're dealing with RTL script. Yes, this is a hack and yes, it will give poor results in some situations, but at least it's a fallback.

Comment: if you use the private area it wont be rtl